# Solving the system of equations $\begin{cases} R \sin r = H \sin \theta \\ R \cos r = H \cos \theta \end{cases}$ for $R$ and $r$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, systems-of-equations, roots

I am working on a program which will predict the tides, but have come across a problem when using the simplified harmonic method of tidal prediction, I understand the whole thing but cannot do the following, this is what I have so far:

$$R\sin(r) = H\sin(\theta)$$

$$R\cos(r) = H\cos(\theta)$$

How do I obtain the values of just R and r alone?

EDIT 2! it is slightly more complex than first explained, this is more like what I am trying to work with:

$$R\sin(r) = A\sin(Y) + B\sin(Z)$$

$$R\cos(r) = A\cos(Y) + B\cos(Z)$$

Thanks.

Comment: Trivially, $r = \theta + 2\pi k$ (for all $k \in \mathbb Z$) and $R = H$ (other solutions may exist as well)...

Comment: And I was reading the title thinking "I've never heard of sine factorial before".

Comment: Haha, I have now edited the title!

Comment: @Paul Reed: What is the difference? denote $H=A+B$...

Comment: Final question update! The angles were not the same, there are two angles used, Y and Z.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that $\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1$. Hence, by squaring both equations and adding you have:
$$R^2=R^2(\sin^2r+\cos^2r)=H^2(\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta)=H^2$$
Hence $R=\pm H$.
From here you know that $\sin r=\pm\sin\theta$ (depending on the value of $H$). Assuming that $H,R\geq0$ then you have $\sin r=\sin\theta$. So $r=\theta+2\pi k$

Comment: I have edited the question, reflecting more what I am trying to do,  I can't make your answer work for the new situation!

Comment: That is the same: $R^2=(A+B)^2$...

Comment: Sorry for delay, been spending an age trying to understand the tide tables I am looking at, the final version of the formula is now up; this is why it wasn't working the simple R2 = (A + B)2 I guess! The angles differ among the first and last term, hence the new Y and Z terms.

Comment: That $\sin^2+\cos^2=1$ will get you a long way, @PaulReed.  With your new equations you've got $R^2=A^2+B^2+2 A B \cos{(y-z)}$.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, so to get r could I then just do asine( Asin(Y)+Bsin(Z) /just calculated R) ?

Comment: @Paul Reed: Yes. Remember that $\sin(x)=\sin(x+2\pi)$ and that $\sin(x)=\sin(\pi-x)$.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber I know this is a long time ago, but I used your formula for the application and it worked but now I'm revisiting it as I didn't really understand why it worked. Would you be able to explain? When I try to work it out I only get $R^2cos^2(r) + R^2sin^2(r)$ simplifies to $R^2$ and the same with the rest leaving $R^2 = A^2 + B^2$ where does the $+2ABcos(y-z)$ come from? Thanks