# Simplifying expressions containing sine and cosine

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I wrote a computer programme to predict tides a fair while ago using the simplified harmonic method of tidal prediction, I understood most of this method bar one part where I had to obtain to values $R$ and $r$. I asked a question about this, [Rearranging equations with sine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/218992/rearranging-equations-with-sine) and the solution given worked.

I'm now revisiting this and want to understand the process better, the original expression is below:

$$
R\sin(r) = A\sin M+B\sin S\\
R\cos(r) = A\cos M+B\cos S\\
$$
I need to get the values for $R$ and $r$. I was told to square, then add the expressions, bearing in mind that $\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta = 1$
$$
R^2\sin^2(r) = A^2\sin^2 M+B^2\sin^2 S\\
R^2\cos^2(r) = A^2\cos^2 M+B^2\cos^2 S\\
$$
Would this not reduce down to the following?
$$
R^2 = A^2 + B^2
$$
How does it reduce down to the correct answer below?
$$
R^2 = A^2 + B^2 +2AB\cos(M-S)
$$

Comment: $(a+b) ^2 \neq a^2+b^2$... $(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2+2ab$

Comment: Ahh, the freshman's dream...

Comment: I know what you mean by this, but I don't know how it applies to my question - can you elaborate? Thanks.

Comment: Ok, so $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + b^2 + 2ab$ but I don't see where I am adding two values $(a+b)$ then squaring them afterwards? Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** You have squared the binomial incorrectly.

$$(\underbrace{A\sin M}_{\textrm{first term}} + \underbrace{B\sin S}_{\textrm{second term}})^2 = A^2\sin^2 M + 2AB\sin M \sin S + B^2\sin^2 S
$$

and similarly for the other expression.

Answer (score 1):

$R^2\sin^2 r = A^2\sin^2 M+B^2\sin^2 S+2AB\sin M \sin S\\
R^2\cos^2 r = A^2\cos^2 M+B^2\cos^2 S+2AB\cos M \cos S\\$

So you have then

$R^2=A^2+B^2+2AB(\sin M \sin S+\cos M\cos S)$...

Comment: Thanks, I'm assuming this was simplified a little from $2R^2 = 2A^2...$ etc. How then does the $2AB(sinMsinS+cosMcosS)$ become $2ABcos(M-S)$

Comment: Is it because of angle sum and difference identities? E.g. $cos(A-B) = cosAcosB + sinAsinB$

Comment: @PaulReed Yes it is $cos(A-B) = cosAcosB + sinAsinB$. However, there is no simplification from $2R^2$... Since you add the $\cos^2$ with the $\sin^2$...

Comment: So @Martigan $R^2sin^2r+R^2cos^2r≠2R^2.1$ ? What does that equal?

Comment: @PaulReed: There is no "$2$" on the right hand side. You have inserted that somehow.

Comment: @MPW Do you not get that when you add the two expressions together?

Comment: @PaulReed: You get $R^2\cdot 1$, not $2R^2\cdot 1$